# Cross-Object SOQL Query

Tags: apex, soql, query, before-trigger, after-trigger

I have a set of custom fields on my Accounts object that depict weather an Account is approved for business with our company. The Approved Date is added via an Approval Process, and Account Status is updated with a simple Time Based workflow. My Goal is to add a time base to send renewal emails to contacts that i mark as "Admin Contacts" or personel like CEO or CFO of the companys we do business with.

i would like to just add the Account Expiration date to each Admin contact, i have achieved this if i place a check mark on the contact. but if a new renewal is initiated the date on the contact wont update unless i uncheck and recheck each admin.

i wrote a trigger and class to achieve this and have tested it many ways and it doesnt update any of the contacts once the Approval Date is changed on the account record.

heres what the Account fields look like:

[image: Account]

Contact Fields:

[image: Contact]

heres my class:

```
    public with sharing class AdmContAcct
{
    public void leadAlerts(List<Account> lstAcct)
    {
        sendAlertsPrivate(lstAcct);
    }

    private void sendAlertsPrivate(List<Account> lstAcct)
    {
        List<Contact> lstUpdateCon = new List<Contact>();

        for(Account acc : lstAcct)
        {
            List<Contact> lstCon = [SELECT Id, Admin_User__c, Account_Expiration__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :acc.Id AND Admin_User__c = true];  

            if(acc.Approved_Date__c != null)
            {
                Date tdy = date.today();
                Date expire = acc.Approved_Date__c.addDays(365);
                boolean approved = expire >= tdy;
                if(!lstCon.isEmpty())
                {
                    for(Contact conLoop : lstCon)//loop through contacts with admin user related to account passed through.
                    {
                        if(approved)
                        {
                            lstUpdateCon.add(new Contact(Account_Expiration__c = expire));
                            //conLoop.Account_Expiration__c = expire;
                            //update conLoop;
                        }
                        else //account not approved
                        {
                            lstUpdateCon.add(new Contact(Account_Expiration__c = null));
                            //conLoop.Account_Expiration__c = null;
                            //update conLoop;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }           
            else//Approved date removed
            {
                if(!lstCon.isEmpty())
                {
                    for(Contact conLoop : lstCon)
                    {
                        lstUpdateCon.add(new Contact(Account_Expiration__c = null));
                        //conLoop.Account_Expiration__c = null;
                        //update conLoop;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(!lstUpdateCon.isEmpty())
        {
            update lstUpdateCon;
        }       
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```
    trigger AdmContAcct on Account (after update) 
{
    AdmContAcct objAcctHandler = new AdmContAcct();

    if (Trigger.IsUpdate)
    {
        objAcctHandler.leadAlerts(Trigger.New);
    }

}
```

i get no errors when saving in the Eclipse IDE but i get no results when updating the account fields.

my questions are:

- Did i incorrectly state my SOQL query? if so how can it be fixed?
- did i incorrectly Loop the contacts?
- Should this have been a before trigger? i have tried it both ways before and after. if it is supposed to be an after trigger did i write the update statements correctly?

Update:

- as Per Adrian i understand that After is correct, he stated that
  Cross-Object Queries must be After Trigger.
- how can i get the SOQL query out of the loop? and what do i have to
  do to fix it?
- will the loop work if i get the query out of the loop?

Comment: Well you definitely didn't bulkify it properly, since you have a query within a loop.

Comment: Answers are 1. Yes - 2. Yes 3. Yes.

Comment: @Ashwani cross-object updates [should be performed in `after` triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm).

Comment: @AdrianLarson oh, I read it like OP is using after event! New answers:- 1. Yes 2. Yes 3. No

Comment: @AdrianLarson how can i get the query out of the loop? will update question.

Comment: You have a few minor optimizations you can do as well. The main one is to remove the `if(! someList.isEmpty() )` checks. None of them in any of your code are necessary. Next, your `if(approved)` section could be written simply: `lstUpdateCon.add(new Contact(Account_Expiration__c = approved?expire: null));` Third, as a matter of style choice, I recommend you adopt something like [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html). Your code would be half as tall, making it easier to read and maintain.

Comment: You have all answers in my post if you would be interested in learning.

Comment: @sfdcfox Appologies for my terrible style. will i get a null pointer if no contacts are selected as admin if i remove the `.isempty()`? and the `if(approved)` has been updated. thank you so much!

Comment: @BryanCerrati Nope. Iterating over an empty list means that the inside part never runs. It's always okay to iterate over an empty loop. There are times when you'd want to check if a list is empty (e.g. before performing a query that you can logically ascertain will not return results), but as long as you're initializing your variables, you don't need to worry about a NullPointerException.

Comment: An `isEmpty` check could never protect you from a null pointer. It would actually throw one if the list is `null`.

Comment: @sfdcfox ok got it i will remove the `isEmpty` checks

Comment: @AdrianLarson ohhhh ok i understand thank you both again.

Comment: how can i bulkify the SOQL statement?

Answer (score 3):

***Answering your questions only:-***

Did i incorrectly state my SOQL query?

> Yes, SOQL in for-loop is highly **not** recommended. What if the for loop
>   cross 100 records. You will get [SOQL 101](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000181404&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=1). So first improvement in the
>   code would be the take out all queries from for loop.

Did i incorrectly Loop the contacts?

> There is no [bulkification](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices). You must query all Contacts together. Query
>   all Contacts for all Accounts. Keep then in collection and access from
>   the Map only. [Collection must be used for such situations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_bulk_idioms.htm).

Should this have been a before trigger? i have tried it both ways before and after. if it is supposed to be an after trigger did i write the update statements correctly?

> Email operation would be sent on After events only. Your update DML is in `for-loop` so, again an issue ([DML 151](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112655/system-limitexception-too-many-dml-statements-151)).

Note: Go though links provided with each answers to avoid these issues.

Comment: i dont understand how to get it out of the loop. let alone the links you posted about bulkification in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from not bulkifying your code, it looks like you are not referencing the account in your where clause. Try the below.

```
List<Contact> lstCon = [SELECT Id, Admin_User__c, Account_Expiration__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :acc.Id AND Admin_User__c = true];
```

Comment: This assessment is not correct, and your query won't even compile.

Comment: he's right @AdrianLarson. You try to compare Id of Contact object in SOQL with Id of Account (acc.Id). What error do you get, when trying to compile?

Comment: @ytiq it was incorrect. edits were made.